# Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am trying to bind a list to drop down in JSP. Below is my controller and JSP.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WeatherServiceController {

    @Value("#{'${countryList}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> countries;

    @ModelAttribute("CountriesList")
    private List<String> getCountries(){
        System.out.println(countries.size());
        return countries;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getweather", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getWeather(){
        Place p = new Place();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("place",p);
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Weather Service Client - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome to Weather Service</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="place" action="getWeather">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="country">Country:</form:label></td>
            <td>

                <form:select path="country" items="${CountriesList}">

                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting error like "Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items". Country list is not coming in jsp page. Please help me what I did wrong here.

Comment: Most likely items="${CountriesList}" doesn't find your list. Prefix it with the name for WeatherServiceController

Answer (score 1):

It is working now.
I have added below line in jsp page.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

I thought by default "isELIgnored" is set to false, so I haven't included earlier. After including this page is binding list result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering your own question. This helped me :D